# exhibition medals

Tags: meaning-in-context

What is the exact meaning of "exhibition medals" in the following passage? For more information, I  wrote the passage in detail. It is from the book Iranian-Russian Encounters, p. 124.

> Meanwhile, Wortman was using the company as a dumping-ground for imported second-hand junk (a piano, an organ, equipment for extracting natural gas, butter churns, discarded parts of public urinals) – hardly surprising, given his ‘inglorious past as a salesman of **exhibition medals**’ (an activity that had led to his banishment from Moscow), of which he bestowed vast quantities
> on road workers at a cost to the company of 300 roubles apiece.

Thanks very much.

Comment: It may be literal: https://www.pinterest.co.uk/bagerap1219/exhibition-medals/

Comment: I've seen old pianos and mechanical devices which advertised that particular model as having won a medal at an industrial exhibition. See [this](https://www.dcmmedals.co.uk/medals-of-the-great-exhibition-1851/) referring to the London 'Great Exhibition', which apparently issued souvenir medals as well. Presumably this man had been selling such things as 'valuable collectors' items'.

Comment: Even [seeing the context](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Iranian_Russian_Encounters/VCTipPJdKBwC?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=exhibition%20medals), it's unclear to me what "exhibition medals" are. Parsing the punctuation religiously, though, suggests that he was giving such medals to the road workers (rather than the "second-hand junk"), presumably as motivational rewards.

Comment: Hi! Were that medals "fake medals"? or, were they used for fraud?